# Android MenuItemCompat.getActionView always returns null

Tags: android, null, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a simple activity

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_search_city);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_action, menu);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

with this menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/tool"
    app:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search City"
        app:actionviewclass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showasaction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

(Note that if I use res-auto instead of tool, the project doesn't build saying showasaction and actionviewclass are not found...)

with this style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
</resources>
```

But when I start the app I get a null pointer because MenuItemCompat.getActionView returns null..

Could someone point me where is the mistake?

ps: I have this is my gradle 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

- You must use `res-auto` - the `tool` namespace set gets completely stripped before inclusion in your APK
- Names are case sensitive - you need to use `app:actionViewClass` and `app:showAsAction` as per the [Action Bar training](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView)

Comment: Damn it! I can't believe this hours of searching and the problem is that it was case sensitive.. Thank you for pointing me this out! It works now I get this searchView in the actionBar displayed.